# GL_SCISSOR_TEST causing strange rendering artefacts

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, jogl, clipping

I'm working with OpenGL 2 ES 2 in an orthographic 2D setting, coded with JOGL & java.

I'm having an issue with GL_SCISSOR_TEST, where certain polygons in my rounded rectangle object disappear when the test is enabled, but are fine when it's disabled..

My scenario is I'm drawing a rounded rectangle, using TRIANGLE_FAN. I'm trying to draw to a sub-rectangle within this shape. I've been successful with this until now. My technique relies on clipping to the sub-area I'm wanting to render, in order to avoid the texture being stretched across the whole rounded rectangle ( my texture is CLAMP_TO_EDGE ). However I've noticed under very specific circumstances, certain poly's pixels arn't rendered.. but if I disable scissor test then everything is fine ( except I render to the whole rounded rectangle which isn't what I desire )

I'm also confused as to how the scissor test is culling a polygon's pixels, when the test is per pixel? not per vertex.

Please see the image below:

[image]

I've noticed the issue appears & disappears as I resize the window, even though the component drawn is the same size each time.

I've tried looking into face culling, z-plane conflicts, among others things, but no joy.

I've drawn other shapes ( ovals, rectangles etc ) and they appear to be fine, which worries me that it is something to do with my rounded rectangle.. But if it were, would the blue rounded rectangle in the image not break in the same way? drawing to the whole shape, or any sub area that encompasses the centre of the shape appear to be fine..

My settings:

- Depth testing is always disabled.
- Culling is always disabled.
- Stencilling is enabled & disabled on demand.
- Vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Center
- Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile
- Version: 3.0 Mesa 9.0
- GL Profile: GLProfile[GL2/GL2.hw]
- Is GLES2 Compatible: true
- Are NPOTT Available: true

I'm all out of ideas of what it could be or how to proceed..

UPDATE:

I've had the issue crop up when drawing sub regions inside paths too:

[image]

Comment: How many vertices do you have in a single triangle fan for that? I've seen weird bugs when more than 256 vertices where in a single fan primitive, on some implementations (don't remember exactly which one).

Comment: Oh really? The rounded rectangle is 42 verts & the path is 82, but the path is drawn differently. In order to counteract concave shapes overlapping themselves when drawn with triangle fan, I draw the path into the stencil buffer only, then draw a simple quad over the where I want to texture, & the stencil buffer test takes care of the rest. Its interesting that the problem occurs with paths, seen as really I'm only texturing a quad... yet the artefacts look like they're from the triangle fan...

Comment: The problem only occurs when the rectangle for the scissor test moves within the bounds of the shapes being drawn. When set to their bounds or greater there are no rendering issues. With that said, I could leave the scissor test there & use the stencil buffer for sub-clipping within the shape. Although this incurs more overhead on the GPU, it does give me the advantage that I can draw any arbitrary shape within the confines of another arbitrary shape, not just rectangles - which is all scissor test will give.

Comment: How big/small your coordinate values and what type used? Maybe during clipping calculations some invalid values appears because of insufficient precision.

Comment: The Scissor test has to be set with integers and I'm using float values for the vertices, in keeping with samples I've seen. The objects in the examples above are a few hundred pixels across.